Why doesn't a JavScript .submit() call trigger the forms onsubmit event?
I have this form:
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        print_r($_POST);
        exit;
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <script>            
            setTimeout(function ()
            {
                document.forms[0].submit();
            }, 2000);
    </script>

    <form action="modaldialog-form-submit.html" method="post" id="myForm" onsubmit="alert('Why am I not seeing this alert when the form is submitted by JavaScript?');" >
        <input type="text" name="myText" value="Some text..." /><br />
        <textarea name="myTextarea">A text area</textarea><br />
        
        <input type="radio" value="1" name="myRadio" checked />Radio1<br />
        <input type="radio" value="22" name="myRadio" />Radio2<br />
        <input type="radio" value="333" name="myRadio" />Radio3<br />
        
        <select name="mySelect">
            <option value="first">First</option>
            <option value="second">Second</option>
            <option value="third">Third</option>
        </select>
        <p />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>

When you click the submit button the onsubmit event is fired and you see the alert. But when the document.forms[0].submit() method is called it does not fire the onsubmit event.
Why is that?

The question title says the opposite of the body text. Which is it?

If you do need to fire the submit event via JavaScript, you can trigger a click event on the submit button. document.forms["myForm"].elements.submit.click() assuming you give the submit input name="submit". But most of the time a submit button that the user clicks themself should suffice. If there is a submit button in a form the submit can also be triggered by pressing Enter while the focus is on any <input> within the form.
